# how to find a tetrahedron in $R^n$ to bound an ellipsoid (again in $R^n$)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computational-geometry, polyhedra

Assume you are given the following ellipsoid in $R^n$:

$E: (c+\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix_i)^2$,

where $x_i$ 's are the coordinate variables. c and $\alpha_i$'s are constant.

now the question is how to find a tetrahedron in this space to circumscribe(bound) this ellipsoid E. The tetrahedron has n+1 vertices. so we are looking for n+1 points to surround the E. of course this may have many solutions but one is enough.

Comment: take any (non-colinear) 4 tangent planes and compute intersection ? Or maybe this would not work in R^n ?

Comment: good idea, thanks, I will examine this to see how it works.

Comment: unfortunately this idea does'nt seem to work even in 2D. assume you have an ellipse in 2D and wanna find a triangle to surround it. choosing the points to make tangent is quite tricky

Comment: For the first 2 points you can just choose then randomly on the ellipse (is it finding a point + tangent on an ellipse that you estimate tricky ?) . The last point is more tricky to choose, yes. I would choose the halfway normal at the 2 points, find the intersection of the ellipse with the corresponding line, and take the furthest point.  I'm very confident it is easy in 2D and 3D. not sure for more.

Comment: BTW  the object you mean in n D is not a tetraedron (= 4 points), but is called a simplex.

Comment: what is halfway normal? you mean prependicular bisector? How about in 3D?

Comment: Average of a vectors is always well defined. in 3D I would take the 3 first points random on the ellipsoid and select the 4th as above.